# JSS layout api returns 404 when item requested by display name

Tags: jss, sitecore-api

We are trying to use display names for URLs and it doesn't work with JSS.
E.g. we have a page "search" which has a display name in NL: zoeken.

- when I request `http://localhost:3000/en/search` , the JSS api call is `http://local.sc/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=%2Fsearch&sc_lang=en` (I've omitted api key), and it returns page data -> **OK**
- when I request `http://localhost:3000/nl/zoeken`, the JSS api call is `http://local.sc/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=%2Fzoeken&sc_lang=nl`, and it returns 404 -> **NOK**

We use Sitecore 9.1 initial release. Looks like a bug, but can I maybe there's a workaround? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Actually, the problem happens not only in connected mode but also in integrated.

E.g. if I request `http://local.sc/nl/zoeken` - the page will be rendered, because in that case Item resolution pipeline runs and sets item correctly based on the display name.

However, if I request `http://local.sc/en/search` and then using the language switcher will try to navigate to `/nl/zoeken`, this will fail, because React router takes over the navigation and instead of requesting the whole page from the server, it only tries to retrieve `/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=%2Fzoeken&sc_lang=nl` which return 404.

Concluding the above, I think this is a **bug** in Sitecore, particularly in the item resolution pipeline of the Layout Service.

Comment: first thing I would test if everything is published

Comment: and also check if there is a version for the "zoeken" page created in that language

Comment: @Tony: I work on the local site, it only uses master db, so publishing is out of equation ;)

Comment: @AbhayDhar: yes, there's a version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in pre-9.2 versions of Sitecore JSS. So you have 3 options:

- Upgrade to 9.2 and use newer JSS version which has this bug fixed
- Ask Sitecore Support to provide a fix for your version of Sitecore
- As a do-it-yourself workaround, compare the implementation of the `Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc.ItemResolving.ItemResolver` class from 9.2 version of JSS with the one from your version of Sitecore and implement a custom resolver based on the differences. After that you can replace the default implementation with your custom one in Sitecore DI configuration code:

  `serviceCollection.Remove(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IItemResolver, ItemResolver>());
  serviceCollection.AddTransient<IItemResolver, YourFixedResolver>();`